# Unable to compile an existing project because Compass can't find it

Tags: css, frameworks, sass, compass-sass, zurb-foundation

I just installed the foundation in my application base directory by executing the following command:

```
compass create myprojectname -r zurb-foundation --using foundation
```

Now I have open the sass/_settings.scss file and I have un-comment the 66th line that is the following:

```
$include-html-classes: true;
```

finaly, I try to compile my foundation project in order to include the html classes by executing the following command:

```
compass compile
```

but I am getting the following result in my command prompt:

```
Nothing to compile. If you're trying to starta new project, you have left off the directory argument.
Run "compass -h" to get help.
```

also, based on this page : http://foundation.zurb.com/old-docs/f3/compass.php I try to compile my scss code by using the command:

compass watch

but again I am getting the same message as with compile argument next to compass.

**Note**: I am executing the above commands in the same directory I run the first command for the foundation project creationg.

**Note**: I am very new user on compass, sass, foundation framework. Actually, today is the first time I am using them, so I am not expirienced user. Please be kind with me :)

Is there anybody to help me with that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `compass create [directory_name]`, Compass creates your project within `./[directory_name]` relative from your current directory (running `compass create` without the directory name would have created the project in the current directory).  In order to compile or watch a Compass project, you need to do either of the following things:

- Tell Compass where your project is via `compass compile [path_to_config.rb]`
- Change to the directory where config.rb is found and run `compass compile`

Alternately, you could move your config.rb to where you want to run your command.  Just make sure you edit the paths to directories configured within said file.