# Compile compass styles into arbitrary build directory

Tags: css, build, sass, compass-sass

I have my SCSS files in `assets/styles/` and `config.rb` relative to the project root. My build process allows the user to create any arbitrary build directory and build from there. So I'd like to be able to do this (starting from the project root):

```
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ compass compile ../
```

And I would like this to generate the CSS files in `build/styles/`. Of course, I don't want to hardcode the `build` directory in `config.rb`. Instead, I want to set `css_dir` relative to the directory I'm running `compass` from. Unfortunately, Compass seems to treat everything relative to the project root.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: My alternative solution is to have a script generate the appropriate `config.rb` in the build directory and just do `compass compile` from there.

Comment: What you're asking for is not how Compass was designed to work.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17728908/unable-to-compile-an-existing-project-because-compass-cant-find-it