# Compass can't find any sass files to compile (Windows)

Tags: windows, powershell, sass, compass, gumby-framework

Whenever I run `compass compile` from Windows powershell I get the following error:

```
Compass can't find any Sass files to compile.
Is your compass configuration correct?.
If you're trying to start a new project, you have left off the directory argument.
Run "compass -h" to get help
```

The directory that I am running this from is `C:\Website\Reboot\Frontend` and the contents of the directory are a `_custom.scss` file and an `index.html` file.

What's wrong? All similar questions haven't helped me. The directory path doesn't have `[` or `]` or anything like that.

If anyone is wondering I'm following this ['guide'](http://gumbyframework.com/docs/) to learn how to use Gumby: Apparently when I run `compass compile` it is supposed to generate a css file from my scss file but that doesn't happen. Apparently it can't even detect my .scss file.

I've already tried uninstalling sass, compass, modular-scale and ruby and reinstalling them again. It didn't help.
.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17728908/unable-to-compile-an-existing-project-because-compass-cant-find-it

Comment: Here is an answer for your question http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#partials

Comment: @Ikhtiyor I tried chaning the name to custom.scss Thad didn't help either. Same error message.